# Why does setting my column as Always Encrypted change its collation from SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS to Latin1_General_BIN2?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, collation, always-encrypted

I am encrypting a `VARCHAR(50) NULL` column as randomized. When doing this, the collation is changed from `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` to `Latin1_General_BIN2`.

I cannot find any resources explaining why this happens, and I want to understand what the purpose of the collation change is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2017 documentation:
Always Encrypted is not supported for the columns with the below characteristics:
(...)
String (varchar, char, etc.) columns with non-bin2 collations
(...)

Source: [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Looks like it is changing in SQL Server 2019:

Since its initial release, Always Encrypted has had a restriction regarding the use of collations: non-BIN2 collations are not allowed for character string columns encrypted using deterministic encryption. This restriction also applies to enclave-enabled string columns.

The use of non-BIN2 collations is permitted for character string columns encrypted with randomized encryption and enclave-enabled column encryption keys. However, the only new functionality that is enabled for such columns is in-place encryption. To enable rich computations (pattern matching, comparison operations), you must ensure the column uses a BIN2 collation.

[Configure Always Encrypted with secure enclaves](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-enclaves?view=sqlallproducts-allversions)

Comment: This is happening with a randomized encryption type. Seems like BIN2 is the right way to go no matter what though.